# How to align my table to start from right?

Tags: python, alignment

I want the numbers in the table to align right like presented, how to do that?

Thanks, already!

input:

```
for i in range (1,11):
    i == i*10
    print(f'{i}\t{i*i}\t{i*i*i}')
```

output:

```
1   1   1
2   4   8
3   9   27
4   16  64
5   25  125
6   36  216
7   49  343
8   64  512
9   81  729
10  100 1000
```

wanted output:

```
 1   1    1
 2   4    8
 3   9   27
 4  16   64
 5  25  125
 6  36  216
 7  49  343
 8  64  512
 9  81  729
10 100 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use str.format

```
for i in range (1,11):
    print('{:>3}  {:>3}  {:>3}'.format(i, i*i, i*i*i))
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! Actually found out this to be even better if used {:>4} instead of {:>3} since the largest number is 4 digits.

Comment: @kkrisu i wont post as a seperate answer as @mad_ alredy answers this but you can also use this format in f-string without a call to `.(format)` as `print(f'{i:>2}\t{i*i:>3}\t{i*i*i:>4}')`